# How to iterate through an array and output certain words in a bash script?

Tags: arrays, bash, grep

I am writing a basic bash script to iterate through an array and I have to output the words starting with the letters 't' and 'm'. I used grep to obtain the words starting with certain letters, but I am unable to output more than one letter. How do I use grep to search for more than one starting letter? Or is there a better way to approach this?

```
 #!/bin/bash
Unix=( "car" "hello" "tony" "mustard" );
echo ${Unix[@]}

echo "Here are the words starting with t + m: "
for i in ${Unix[@]}
do
    echo $i | grep '^\t'
done
```

Comment: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25821/grep-how-to-add-an-or-condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest:

```
grep -e '^t' -e'^m'
```

or

```
grep -E '^(m|t)'
```

---

See: `man grep`

Comment: @MiSully Consider accepting the answer by clicking the green mark next to it if it solves your problem

Comment: I suggest to replace `echo $i | grep ...` with `if [[ "$i" =~ ^(m|t) ]]; then echo "$i"; fi`. This does not require an external program (`grep`) and no pipe (two new processes).